# tvOS - Change color of navigation item's title

Tags: uinavigationitem, tvos

In iOS I used to change color of the navigation item's title using this code:

```
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

but in tvOS I get the error:

> UITextAttributeTextColor is unavailable: not available in tvOS

Any work around to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` instead of `UITextAttributeTextColor`?

`UITextAttributeTextColor` was deprecated in iOS7.